# C# Regex word match extractor

Tags: c#, regex

ok i have a list of domains

for example

```
dogstoday . com
catstoday . com
petstoday . com
dogsnow . org
dogsabc . net
catlitter . info
```

i want a regex that will give me all domains that has the word i specify, for example dogs or cats

if i give dogs it should return

```
dogstoday.com
dogsnow.org
dogsabc.net
```

can any one tell me how to do this in c# ?

Comment: May I interest you in grep instead?

Answer (score 4):

If the domains always start with the word you provide as in your example, you can just use `StartsWith` otherwise you can simply use `Contains`. For something simple as this you don't need regular expressions.

Comment: I never understood what jwz had against regular expressions, but now I think I can see where his famous quote would apply.

Comment: I love regular expressions, I just don't believe they are needed for each and every task.

Comment: there are like 70,000 domains in a text file
and i have to remove only domains that match the word i specify.

Comment: A regex will have to search all 70,000 domains as well if that is your concern.

Comment: Don't you know? Regexes are complicated, so they're better!

Answer (score 2):

Does this need to be done with a regex? Why not just loop over all the domains and check if they contain the word you're looking for?

[String.Contains()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/StringContainsastring.htm)

Answer (score 2):

the regex is

/dogs/i

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I think [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) would be better, but something like ...

```
Regex.Match( yourBigString, @".*dogs*.*[.com|.net|.org]" );
```

You should be careful of the domain as you might get some site like .au or .jp or whatever, but this will get anything with dogs in it followed by .com or .net or .org.  You can replace "dogs" with anything you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
string line;
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("dogs", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = System.IO.File.OpenText("domains.txt"))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (r.IsMatch(line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(domain);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the domain is a huge text file with 70,000 lines of domains

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just need to use the [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(VS.80).aspx) method.

Comment: the words can be in between also